# SPSS gives out wrong N calculation in crosstabs

Tags: spss

I asked SPSS to calculate a crosstab for me, but the N comes out as N=1001, when - looking at the numbers - it should be N=1002?

How could this be possible?

Thank you for your help!

[picture of reverenced crosstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSYO1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I haven't seen yor data structure I am not sure if this is what the problem is caused by, but this problem has been reported by IBM before for string variables. In case you have stored the data as a string varaible (eg. "35 bis 54 Jahre", I would recommed recoding it either numerically or into shorter strings (max. 8 characters).
Here is the Link to IBMs page: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/crosstabs-display-wrong-count-and-totals-large-dataset-and-long-string-variable-table